# Django best practice: where to put an aggregation method

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.5, django-managers

I have a best-practice question:

I have a model `Score` which contains a value and a ForeignKey to another model. It's my aim to make it possible to call `account.scores.total_score()` and it will return the sum of the values of all scores in the account.

```
class Score(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='scores')
```

I was thinking about writing a `ScoreManager` and `ScoreQuerySet` to handle this access easily.

```
class ScoreQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def total_score(self):
        return self.aggregate(Sum('value'))

class ScoreManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ScoreQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Score(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='scores')
    objects = ScoreManager()
```

This does only work if I call `account.scores.all().total_score()` but not directly with `account.scores.total_score()`. This doesn't work, because somehow my model does not register the new Manager and QuerySet on the relationship. But maybe this isn't the best practice, so I don't need to take time to fix this and should choose another way.
So what do you guys think about this? Should I create a `total_score()` function in the `Account` model?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you always need to calculate the total score associated with an account, why not add it as a method to your Account model?

class Account(models.Model):
    ...

```
def get_total_score(self):
    return self.scores.aggregate(Sum('value'))

# or even as a property:
@property
def total_score(self):
   return self.scores.aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

Comment: I also was thinking about this, but then it would be a problem using the Account model without the Score model (they are in different apps).

Comment: ah, that makes sense. In that case, I'm not sure how you could get the Score's manareg methods on the foreign key relation. I'll keep googling.